# Tkinter: Return array from a function

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter

I am trying to create a window in which I can enter different values.
The window should adapt dynamically to the data frame.
This works quite well so far.
Now I want to output the input as an array.
The array can be printed in the function as well.

Certainly a stupid question...but how would I get access to the array outside of the function?

Normally, I get access to the return value as follow:

```
def x(y):
    y+1
    return y

y2 = x(2)
print(y2)
--> 3
```

It is the first time I am working with tkinter.
Usually, I would get the `Array` with something like this:

```
ar = d.apply(self)
```

But then I got this: `invalid command name ".!mydialog.!frame.!entry"`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog

class MyDialog(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
        d2={}
        f={}
        self.entries=[]
        for i in range(len(df_data_1.columns) -1 ):
            Label(master, text=df_data_1.columns[i]).grid(row=i)
            entry = Entry(master)
            entry.grid(row=i, column=1)
            self.entries.append(entry)

    def apply(self):
        Array=[]
        i=0
        for entry in self.entries:
            value = entry.get()
            print(df_data_1.columns[i], value)
            Array = np.append(Array, value)
            i=i+1
        return Array

root = Tk()
d = MyDialog(root)
```

Can anyone help me to get the `Array` from the function?

Comment: I believe Array is a built in function. You may want to change that name to `array` or something else. Also from outside of the class I believe you need to do `d.apply()` and not `d.apply(self)`.

Comment: @Mike-SMT, Array is not a built-in function. There is a standard module named `array`, and a type defined in that module named `array`, but they're both lower case.

Comment: @Kevin hum ok. Maybe I am just thinking about VBA.

Comment: @Mike-SMT  I tried both d.apply() and d.apply(self) i get the same error

Comment: After some testing with your code I am getting the same error and I am unsure as to why. I believe it may have something to do with the missing `__init__` and `super()` but when I tried that it did not seam to help. Have you considered building this in your own `toplevel` window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI programming works different than procedural programming does because it's "event-driven" which means it keeps running in an infinite loop processing user input until it ends. The `simpledialog.Dialog` has such a loop in it in it's constructor, which only returns when the dialog window is dismissed or ends. It is what calls the `apply()` method when the user clicks on the <kbd>OK</kbd> button, so that is where you have to do something to make it possible to retrieve the value later after the user event-processing loop ends.

To work around that and allow you to use it the way you want, I've defined a function called `get_array()` which creates the tkinter `root` window, hides it, and then invokes the dialog and waits for it to end. To make it possible to return the `Array`, I have made it an attribute of the `MyDialog` class instance so it can be accessed after the dialog itself has ended. So `get_array()` returns that as its result.

```
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog

class MyDialog(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
        d2={}
        f={}
        self.entries=[]
        for i in range(len(df_data_1.columns)-1):
            Label(master, text=df_data_1.columns[i]).grid(row=i)
            entry = Entry(master)
            entry.grid(row=i, column=1)
            self.entries.append(entry)

    def apply(self):
        """ Copy Entry values into an np.array attribute. """

        self.Array = np.array([])  # Create empty attribute array.
        for i, entry in enumerate(self.entries):
            value = entry.get()
            print(df_data_1.columns[i], value)
            self.Array = np.append(self.Array, value)  # Update attribute.


def get_array():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    d = MyDialog(root)
    # Return dialog "Array" attribute if it has one.
    return getattr(d, "Array", None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = get_array()
    print(result)
```

Comment: @Jannes: That's good news. Note you might want to use `value = float(entry.get())` to append numeric values instead of strings to `self.Array`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
Array=[]
...
Array = np.append(Array, value)
```

is incorrect - you are mixing numpy and normal arrays.

Just replace `Array = np.append(Array, value)` with `Array.append(value)`.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: `[]` is not a normal array. It's a list. There are [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) in the Python standard library, but if your code doesn't have `import array`, you're not using them.

Comment: I changed it. But it doesn't work. I don't think the problem is the array. It still works in the function. The way I want to retrieve the array is probably wrong.